# ASP.NET Core How to specify the route for the "example.com" and "example.com/" (home pages)

Tags: asp.net-core

I updated my asp.net framework application to core. When my site was in .net framework the urls www.example.com and www.example.com/ worked. but now with core I get 404. I don't know why exactly it worked because in my .net framework RouteConfig.cs file I didn't specify any entry related to these routes it just worked and I didn't care now with core it doesn't work.

wwww.example.com/

www.example.com

In .net core Startup class I tried:

The code below gives 404.

```
  routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action}", defaults: new { controller = "Controller", action = "Home" });
```

The code below gives: The route template cannot start with a '/' or '~' character.

```
         routes.MapRoute(name: "home", template: "/", defaults: new { controller = "Controller", action = "Home" } );
```

It doesn't work either.

```
 routes.MapRoute(name: "home", template: "", defaults: new { controller = "Controller", action = "Home" } );
```

I know that the issue can be caused by web server configuration so I can update the question with additional information if needed.

Comment: Sorry for the tags, the page couldn't show the tags so I posted the question without tags.

Comment: I think the issue is because I'm using attribute routing in my controller "Controller". I think it is not possible to use convention routing and attribute routing at same time. I took the attribute routing from the controller and the first route of my question worked.